# Unexpected result after calling RPC 'listaccounts', 'getaccountaddress', 'getreceivedbyaddress' sequentially

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

```
bitcoin > bitcoin-cli listaccounts
{
  "": 5648.99996160
}

bitcoin > bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress ""
mui4xgNgZBr3XhdL4dDDHkRFEvSXZmSi7t

bitcoin > bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress mui4xgNgZBr3XhdL4dDDHkRFEvSXZmSi7t
0.00000000
```

I expect it will return 5648.99996160 after calling 'getreceivedbyaddress'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An account can have multiple associated addresses. Presumably you had another address associated with `""` beforehand, and received money using that address.

The `getaccountaddress` RPC call gives a fresh address. If money had been received already on the previous account address, a new one is created and associated with the account.

Comment: Thank you! However I still get problem. I call RPC **getaddressesbyaccount** and get 3 addresses. Then I call RPC **getreceivedbyaddress** for each 3 address, but the result are all 0.00000000.

Comment: Did you send money to any of those 3 addresses?

Comment: No. However, I expect one of the addresses should have money because the result of RPC "listaccounts" shows there is money in the account.

Comment: getreceivedbyaddress shows (surprise!) how much was received by the address. If you literally tell me you never sent money to any of them, then by definition the response should be 0. There are plenty of other ways through which the account may have been credited before.

Comment: Like what kind of ways? Does it related to regtest mode?(because I am using regtest mode)

Comment: You could have received money using a `getnewaddress` call before any of those 3, or using the `move` command you can move money from other accounts (even if that makes those others negative).